# Select2 on dynamic modal input

Tags: jquery-select2

I am displaying multiple dynamic modals to update some data.

```
<div class="modal fade experience-details exp_update" id="editExperienceModal_{{$exp->id}}" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

My modal's id goes like this editExperienceModal_1,editExperienceModal_2,etc..

Here is the select2 input

```
<select class="form-control sub-select2" name="clinic_name" id="select2_clinic_update_{{$exp->id}}" style="width:100%"></select>
```

If it's not been a dynamic content i can invoke select2 and dropdownParent like this

```
$("#select2_clinic_update").select2({
  placeholder: 'Select clinic name',
  dropdownParent: $('#editExperienceModal_'),
  ......
  ......
```

How do i invoke select2 for dynamically created inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found the solution

```
<select class="form-control sub-select2 select2_clinic_update" name="clinic_name" id="select2_clinic_update_{{$exp->id}}" style="width:100%">
   <option value="{{$exp->clinic_id}}" selected="selected">{{$exp->clinic->be_name}}</option>
</select>
```

i provided a class to the select2 and intialize select2 with class name.

```
$(".select2_clinic_update").select2({
  placeholder: 'Select clinic name',
  // dropdownParent: $('#editExperienceModal_1'),
  minimumInputLength: 2,
```

I removed `tabindex="-1"` from parent modal, so didn't need `dropdownParent` in select2.